# Phrase for "putting one's plans into action"

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I am looking for a phrase, metaphor, or cliche to mean "putting one's plans into action".

I am using it in the following sentence.

> As the events of the play proceed, however, Hamlet becomes increasingly hesitant about following through with his plans. He wastes much of his time ruminating on whether or not he should [insert phrase here].

The wording of the sentence is likely subject to change depending on what phrase I use, but that is the general idea.

Comment: a simple "act" could work.

Comment: @AverageGatsby You're right, sometimes simple is best...

Comment: Or simply 'implement' or 'execute' them.

Comment: @idunno I'm guessing that, like myself, you considered these too obvious to submit as an answer. I consider that to be worth a hat, never mind rep points.

Comment: @AverageGatsby That's dangerously close to a pun. Mind you, '... execute his plans ...' is also quite near to the bone.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ha/thanks!  Agreed too obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People often **execute** plans, [eg](https://books.google.com/books?id=V_IV1QqVK04C&pg=PT189&lpg=PT189&dq=%22execute%20his%20evil%20plan%22&source=bl&ots=jwHha-brHz&sig=v85nS4b6HtVH8iK-s2w8arx2UcY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8obFVJWXDon5yQTfxIHoBQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22execute%20his%20evil%20plan%22&f=false):

> He is able to trick Uriel, an Archangel, easily and get closer to Paradise to **execute** his evil plan to corrupt and destroy Man.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/execute):

> to carry out; accomplish:
>   to execute a plan or order.

Comment: No mention of idunno?

Answer (score 3):

The following is often used when the prospect is daunting:

> **grasp the nettle**            (UK)
>
> to force yourself to be brave and do something that is difficult or
>   unpleasant

{[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/grasp-the-nettle)}

An equivalent expression is **bite the bullet**, but how suitable this would be when talking about Hamlet is debatable.

Comment: Grasp the nettle seems particularly appropriate for Hamlet.

Answer (score 0):

**"set off"** or **"activate"**

- As the events of the play proceed, however, he wastes his time ruminating whether or not he should **set off/activate his plans**.

> - "set off" - to set in motion, cause to begin. -  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set+off?show=0&t=1422227053)
> - "activate" - to set in motion, make active or more active. - [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/activate)